# libvirtd cant start

Tags: 14.04, server

I want to start listening on my server, but libvirtd cant run.
Heres error log:

```
2015-07-09 10:50:25.238+0000: 11569: info : libvirt version: 1.2.2
2015-07-09 10:50:25.238+0000: 11569: error : virAuditOpen:60 : Unable to initialize audit layer: Protocol not supported
2015-07-09 10:50:26.117+0000: 11596: error : virCommandWait:2399 : internal error: Child process (/bin/sh -c 'EBT="/sbin/ebtables"
cmd='\''$EBT -t nat -L'\''
eval res=\$\("${cmd} 2>&1"\)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then  echo "Failure to execute command '\''${cmd}'\'' : '\''${res}'\''.";  exit 1;fi
') unexpected exit status 1
2015-07-09 10:50:26.117+0000: 11596: error : ebiptablesDriverTestCLITools:4274 : Testing of ebtables command failed: Failure to execute command '$EBT -t nat -L' : 'The kernel doesn't support the ebtables 'nat' table.'.
```

Does anyone know how to handle this?

```
Linux mcparadise.pl 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 7 11:35:27 CET 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing nothing about your problem, i think the significant part of the error message is this :

```
'The kernel doesn't support the ebtables 'nat' table.'
```

I did a quick search and there are a few resources

https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#ebtables_Overview
http://www.keypressure.com/blog/linux-bridge-port-security/

Also i saw a kernel module called 'ebtables' and another called 'ebtable_nat' that you can enable with modprobe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ebtables in your linux kernel

Ebtables kernel options:

```
CONFIG_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_BRIDGE=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_T_FILTER=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_T_NAT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_NF_EBTABLES=m
```